# Python simples3 listdir limit the output to 1000 files?

Tags: python, amazon-s3

I am using [simples3](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/simples3) version 1.0. When calling listdir on s3 key that has a lot more than 1000 files, the generator return only the first 1000 files.

The method has an optional limit argument which is None by default. Setting the limit return an empty list. And there is no additional limit to listdir mentioned in the documentation.

Here is a code example, where bucket is simples3 S3Bucket and s3_key is a key in s3 that include over 5000 files under it:

```
count = 0
for file_info in bucket.listdir(prefix=s3_key):
   count += 1

>>> count
1000 ## Expected to be over 5000
```

Is there a limitation that is not documented?
Is there a way with simples3 lib to get all the files under the s3 key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simples3 library is using aws's rest api, which by default [limits the max keys to 1000](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/v2-RESTBucketGET.html).

It's not [documented](http://sendapatch.se/projects/simples3/), but [based on the code](https://github.com/lericson/simples3/blob/master/simples3/bucket.py#L376) can use set the limit using the `limit` key:

```
for file_info in bucket.listdir(prefix=s3_key, limit=10000):
```

> I didn't find any way to set it to unlimited.

Comment: Thanks! As I wrote, I did try to set the limit argument for it just does not return anything:
>>> for file_info in bucket.listdir(prefix=s3_key, limit=10000):
...     count += 1
...     
>>> count
0

Comment: Do you have any idea how can I query more than 1000? Or is it just an aws limit that cannot be workaround?

Comment: Oh, I see that I need to use the NextContinuationToken for querying more than 1000 results and it seems that simples3 does not support it :-/

Comment: The `bucket.listdir(prefix=s3_key, limit=10000)` doesn't work? How about 5000? or 2000? Maybe there is a hard top limit that you can't use number above it...

Comment: And you are correct, the simples3 library doesn't have the implementation of the `NextContinuationToken`.

Comment: Given the apparent age of that library, it probably doesn't even use the List Objects V2 API, which is where the continuation token was introduced (in 2016, iirc).  However, `s.listdir(prefix="test/", marker=...)` *might* be the trick, if it's passing args straight through to the V1 API... here, the value you pass for `marker` is the last key you got from the previous list of 1000.  See the [List Objects V1 API docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketGET.html).

Answer (score 0):

Author of `simples3` here. I'm sorry this stopped working, but that's really on Amazon. As you can see in [the implementation of S3Bucket.listdir](https://github.com/lericson/simples3/blob/master/simples3/bucket.py#L376) there is support for pagination and it should be seamless. If it isn't, then that's because Amazon stopped returning the truncated flag or stopped returning markers to perform pagination.

Comment: Ridiculous that StackOverflow deletes "hello" in the beginning of answers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and for simple3. I could not find a way to use simples3 with pagination so I moved to use boto3.